# SQL range between past date and unbounded preceding

Tags: sql, oracle, range, window-functions

Table structure is as follows

```
country_id | ID | date | same_week_count
```

I am interested in the week number so I am extracting that in the final output.

I would like to count how many times the ID has appeared before that week in each country so I am using

```
count(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY country_id, ID ORDER BY to_number(date, 'IW') RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as ttl_count
```

but I'm getting the following:

```
 country_id  |  ID   |  date  | same_week_count | ttl_count
------------------------------------------------------------
   1         |  123  |   35   |   2             |   1
   1         |  123  |   35   |   2             |   3
```

Where is the 3 coming from? Does unbounded following include the current week or not? Should I have an expression similar to `RANGE BETWEEN to_number(date, 'IW')-1 PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`?

Answer (score 3):

When you write `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` it is a shortcut syntax for `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

So your `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` *does* include the current week number. The count on a given row will include *all* rows (within the partition) having the same week number or less as the row itself - even if those rows actually come *after* the row itself. That is the definition of `RANGE BETWEEN` - otherwise `ROWS BETWEEN` could be an alternative.

But as you want the count of those rows within each partition that has the less than the same week number, you will want to use something like `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` which will include week numbers up to and including *one less than current row*.

Another problem you have is what happens when you cross a year? Is this meant only to be used for data within one calendar year? In week 3 in 2015, do you wish to include data from week 51 in 2014? If yes, then be careful of your `TO_NUMBER` expression - might be better to do `TRUNC(date,'IW')` as in:

```
count(ID) OVER (
  PARTITION BY country_id, ID
  ORDER BY trunc(date, 'IW')
  RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 7 PRECEDING
) as ttl_count
```

The `TRUNC` makes the date become the monday of each week. `7 PRECEDING` then is *7 days* preceding.